# For each loop in JSTL from another file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, el

I want a way where I can get the user to answer a series of questions and then at the end tell them their mark.

so far I have got this

a number of .jsps with each question written inside it. each page has a next button taking them to the next question. the final question links to a page called results.jsp where it needs to work out if they put the right or wrong answer and then tell them their mark.

this is qOne.jsp

```
<form action="/HelloSpring/results" method="post">

    <p> What is the correct wrapper class for the primitive int? </p>
    <input type="radio" name="radios" value="Int">Int<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radios" value="Enum">Enum<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radios" value="integer1">integer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radios" value="Integer2">Integer<br>
    <input type="text" name="elc" autocomplete="off" >name<br>
             <input type="submit" value="Next" >

</form>
<FORM><INPUT Type="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

Once clicked you get to results.jsp

```
<body>
<h2>Result</h2>

<p>Good day ${elc}, you scored ${a} </p>

<c:forEach items="${results}" var="total" >
    ${total};
    ${Score};
    ${score};
</c:forEach>

<section>
<p>Total score: ${total}</p>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the WebController.java file which should deal with the result for the final question (shown above). It runs an if statement and then depending on which if "runs" it will add a 0 or 1 to the hashmap.  At some point I will print out the total of the hash map to show their score and add in the request mappings for other questions. I just want to get the first one working.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String results(Model model, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String elc) {

                Object map2 = session.getAttribute("map");
                HashMap<String, Integer> map = (HashMap<String, Integer>) map2;

                request.getSession().setAttribute("score", "total");

                if(request.getParameter("radios") != null) {
                if(request.getParameter("radios").equals("Int")) {
                    model.addAttribute("Score", 0);
                    System.out.println("Int selected as your answer");
                }
                else if(request.getParameter("radios").equals("Enum")) {
                    model.addAttribute("Score", 0);
                    System.out.println("Enum selected as your answer");
                }
                else if(request.getParameter("radios").equals("integer1")) {
                    model.addAttribute("Score", 0);
                    System.out.println("integer was selected as your answer");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Integer was selected as your answer");
                    model.addAttribute("Score", 1);
                }

            }
                   return "results";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real problem here but if you want to do this I suggest you to do all questions on the front end on a wizard as http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples.

If you make a wizard in front end, you just have to check all the question at the end in the controller and send the result to another jsp. 
You could still keep your jsp and include it in each wizard part if you doesn't want to have a bigger question.jsp file.

In this scenario, the next and previous button will be easy. The score calculation will be easy too.